# Linux: Why does the CPU frequency fluctuate when using the performance governor?

Tags: linux, performance, central-processing-unit, linux-kernel, benchmark

I'm using a Debian 8 amd64 machine for benchmarking. During experimentation, I would like the CPU to operate at a fixed frequency (preferably the maximum possible). This will rule out the CPU clock speed as a source of variation in the results.

After some reading, it seems that the correct thing to do is to change the CPU governor to `performance`, which is described [here in the Linux kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/governors.txt):

> The CPUfreq governor "performance" sets the CPU statically to the
>   highest frequency within the borders of scaling_min_freq and
>   scaling_max_freq.

Sadly, further details about `scaling_min_freq` and `scaling_max_freq` are not supplied. Hopefully it should not matter, as the  CPU frequency used is the maximum value of the interval.

So I've enabled this governor using cpufreq-set:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
performance
performance
performance
performance
```

And for good measure, I also disabled turbo boost mode in the bios:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
1
```

Based on the above description of the performance governor, I would expect no fluctuation in the CPU clock speed. Yet if I repeatedly run `cpufreq-info`, I see the clock speed fluctuating:

```
$ cpufreq-info | grep 'current CPU fr'
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 3.99 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
$ cpufreq-info | grep 'current CPU fr'
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 3.96 GHz.
$ cpufreq-info | grep 'current CPU fr'
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 3.94 GHz.
$ cpufreq-info | grep 'current CPU fr'
  current CPU frequency is 4.01 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 4.00 GHz.
  current CPU frequency is 3.98 GHz.
```

Is this fluctuation due to hardware, the BIOS, the kernel, or some other factor? Is there a way to set the CPU frequency such that it doesn't fluctuate at all?

Comment: What type of server hardware are you using? What are the BIOS power and CPU performance settings of that hardware?

Comment: It's actually a desktop machine with an i7 CPU. I've uploaded dmesg and cpuinfo here: https://gist.github.com/vext01/73eea539eb041acf784b . Re: bios settings, I would need to go to the machine and look. Is there any specific setting you have in mind?

Comment: That's not "much" fluctuation compared to normal pstate variation... :)

Answer (score 9):

After some experimentation, I think I can answer my own question.

As mentioned [in this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121410/setting-cpu-governor-to-on-demand-or-conservative), on certain Intel hardware, there are two ways to manage the CPU frequency:

- Using pstate.
- Using regular ACPI.

When pstate is used, the BIOS has some say over the clock speed, and it seems that this is the source of the fluctuations.

You can force pstate off by appending `intel_pstate=disable` to the kernel arguments (edit `/etc/default/grub` and add the arg to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. Finally run `sudo update-grub`).

After doing this, the output of `cpufreq-info` looks much different, and I also notice that a different set of CPU governors become available (e.g. `ondemand` is now available).

Most importantly, after setting the governor to `performance`, the clock speed is now fixed (in my case to 4.00GHz).

You can look in `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` to determine if pstate or ACPI is being used to scale the CPU. These files can assume the values `acpi-cpufreq` or `intel_pstate`.

Comment: Another trick: use ´lsmod´ to list the modules loaded by the kernel, blacklist every module related to CPU speed scaling/p-state/c-states/whatever and reboot the machine. Search "blacklist kernel modules".

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121410/setting-cpu-governor-to-on-demand-or-conservative

Answer (score 5):

> For contemporary Intel processors, the frequency is controlled by the
>   processor itself and the P-states exposed to software are related to
>   performance levels.  **The idea that frequency can be set to a single**
>   **frequency is fiction for Intel Core processors**. Even if the scaling
>   driver selects a single P state the actual frequency the processor
>   will run at is selected by the processor itself. [1]

[1] https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/intel-pstate.txt

Comment: Interesting. So, does this still apply when I pass `intel_pstate=disable` to the kernel? Am I invoking `"legacy mode" when I do that?

Comment: 1) not sure. need to consult with `Intel Architectures Software Developer's Manual.` 2) yes. PS. You may also want to play with `x86_energy_perf_policy`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Since I am still unsure, I am leaving the question open for now. Maybe someone will shed light on the situation later.

Answer (score -1):

i read this thread because i was too looking to set a fixed frequency to my cpu since the fan don't work anymore ( of course those things happen when your abroad in a lost island for diving leisure ! ) so my point was more to set the lowest frequency ( 800Mhz ) ..i finally succeded making change to the scaling_max_freq in the  /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/
for each cpu of the configuration & now it's fine the frequency is supposed to move from  800Mhz to ....800Mhz . It works and solved the overheating problem i've had experience..( the frequency is now 799Mhz and don't move which allowed the cpu to remain around 50°C!)

PS : i also disable the turbo mode ( 3,1Ghz )