# Why is my scaling_max_freq stuck at 1GHz (on a Core Duo processor)

Tags: central-processing-unit, linux-kernel, frequency

I recently setup an old Thinkpad T60 as a secondary desktop (via a docking station), but when I tried it, it was feeling sluggish and I soon figured that it was somehow stuck at 1GHz, even tho its processor can go up to 1.83GHz (it's a Core Duo T2400).

I'm running Debian stable on this machine and can't figure out how to let it use the higher frequency:

```
~# cd /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq 
cpu0/cpufreq# cat cpuinfo_max_freq 
1833000
cpu0/cpufreq# cat scaling_available_frequencies 
1833000 1333000 1000000 
cpu0/cpufreq# cat scaling_max_freq 
1000000
cpu0/cpufreq# echo 1833000 >scaling_max_freq; cat scaling_max_freq
1000000
cpu0/cpufreq#
```

As you can see, even though 1833000 should be a valid value, when I try to set it, it's immediately (re)set to 1GHz.

Who/what (re)sets it?  Why?  How can I override this?

[ I have seen [Linux: Why does the CPU frequency fluctuate when using the performance governor?](https://serverfault.com/questions/716317/linux-why-does-the-cpu-frequency-fluctuate-when-using-the-performance-governor), but that seems to be another problem since my CPU is not modern enough to have pstates so it is using `acpi-cpufreq` as `scaling_driver`.  ]

The battery is old but still working:

```
% cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent 
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Unknown
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=0
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=10800000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=12133000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=0
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=84240000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=75890000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=66910000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=88
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=92P1133
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=Panasonic
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=  379
%
```

Comment: The battery is probably dead. You can't exceed 1GHz without a battery. Confirm that the battery is dead and I'll post a full explanation.

Comment: The battery is pretty old, but it still holds a bit of a charge.  I've updated my post with the corresponding info.

Comment: Hmm, then it's probably something else. If the battery is physically present, detected, and holds charge, that should be sufficient.